# Confusion in File Operations Of C

Tags: c, file, append, fopen

Here I have one filename and I want to create this file first.
I want to left some bytes in File and than I want to write data.
so here in below code I used `fseek(pFile, 10, SEEK_SET)`.
than I am writing here `"sam"` in file from 11th position.
and than close the file and Again open 4 times this file in append mode and writing "`abc"` at the end of file.
so total bytes in `example.txt` are `25` bytes.
 so file data are like this `..........samabcabcabcabc`.
 But I didn't want "sam" in this file data. Means I want only 22 bytes.
 If I am here dnt use `fputs("sam", pFile);` than its giving only 12 bytes and file data looks like `abcabcabcabc`.

I want output in file like `..........abcabcabcabc`.

In real program I have one function which append data after 10 bytes. and this function call multiple times so how can I achieve this goal?

My sample code is here.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    FILE * pFile;
    pFile = fopen("example.txt", "wb");
    fseek(pFile, 10, SEEK_SET);
    fputs("sam", pFile);
    fclose(pFile);
    append("example.txt");
    append("example.txt");
    append("example.txt");
    append("example.txt");
    return 0;
}

void append(char *file) {
    FILE * pFile;
    pFile = fopen("example.txt", "ab");
    fputs("abc", pFile);
    fclose(pFile);
}
```

Comment: You should check return values from the various functions. I'm not sure if seeking beyond the end of file is legal/portable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `man fopen`

> When you open a file for appending (that is, when the Type parameter
>   is set to a), it is impossible to overwrite information already in the
>   file.

So you cannot overwrite `sam` if you wish to open your file in append mode as you've done in `append()`

Even in `a+` mode of opening, you can reposition (using `fseek`, `rewind`) the internal pointer to anywhere in the file for reading, but writing operations will move it back to the end of file.

The workaround is to use `r+` opening mode the first time , re-position internal pointer using `fseek` and then write `abc`. After that you can call your `append` as usual